# Determining whether a sequence of functions converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on determining whether this sequence of functions converges uniformly or not. Let $f_n(x)=n^2 x(1-x)^n$ on the interval $[0, 1]$. Clearly the pointwise limit of the sequence is the function $f(x) = 0$. If I fix $n$ and take the derivative, I get that the max of the sequence occurs when $x = \frac{1}{n+1}$. Then
 $$ f_n \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\frac{n^{n+2}}{(n+1)^{n+1}} $$

I am stuck here. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You're almost done. Since
$$f_n\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)=n\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-(n+1)}\sim_\infty e^{-1}n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty\ne0$$
then the sequence doesn't converge uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Notice that also by your work you can prove easily that we have the uniform convergence on every interval $[a,1]$ for $0<a<1$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use $\log ab =  \log a + \log b$ and $\frac{\log (1+\epsilon)}\epsilon
\to_{\epsilon\to 0} 1$
:

$$
\log f_n(1/(n+1)) = (n+2)\log n - (n+1)\log(n+1)
\\
= (n+2)\log n- (n+1)\log n  - (n+1)\log (1+1/n)
= \log n - 1+o(1)
\\
f_n(1/(n+1)) = ne^{-1+o(1)}\to \infty
$$

hence the convergence is not uniform.